# Why "CloneWithRows()" don't work with array

Tags: mobile, react-native

I have the code:

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
var ds= new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
});

var messagesArray = [
  {message: "Hello", style: styles.nikkiMes},
  {message: "Okkkk", style: styles.userMes}
];

this.state = {
  messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(messagesArray.slice());
};
```

}

Error in the line:

```
messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(messagesArray.slice());
```

Why i cannot to pass array into cloneWithRows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put a semicolon in your object definition. Different properties are seperated by commas, not semicolons.
**e.g.**

```
obj = {
    var: 'myVar',
    anotherVar: 'myVar2',
}
```

**So this:**

```
this.state = {
    messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(messagesArray.slice());
}
```

**Should be**

```
this.state = {
    messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(messagesArray.slice())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just add a terminator ";" in line 
messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(messagesArray.slice()) 
just remove this and your code is work perfectly.

```
var messagesArray =[{message:"data1"},{message:"data2"},{message:"data3"}];
this.state = {
messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(messagesArray.slice())
}
```